# Tree component is not rendering properly

Tags: angular, angular-material

Nested tree control in angular material is not rendering properly. I have used this link https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples, but its not rendering same as example shown in link.

[image: Tree view rendered in browser]

app.component.html file contains html code for tree view

**app.component.html file**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">

      <mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl" class="example-tree">
        <!-- This is the tree node template for leaf nodes -->
        <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle>
          <li class="mat-tree-node">
            <!-- use a disabled button to provide padding for tree leaf -->
            <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
            {{node.name}}
          </li>
        </mat-tree-node>
        <!-- This is the tree node template for expandable nodes -->
        <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild">
          <li>
            <div class="mat-tree-node">
              <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
                      [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.name">
                <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
                  {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
                </mat-icon>
              </button>
              {{node.name}}
            </div>
            <ul [class.example-tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(node)">
              <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </mat-nested-tree-node>
      </mat-tree>

     </div>
     <div class="col-md-8">
         <p> Drop Area </p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.component.ts file contains typescript code for data source and other tree view initialization code.

**app.component.ts file**

```
import { NestedTreeControl } from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTreeNestedDataSource } from '@angular/material/tree';
import { TREE_DATA, FoodNode }  from '../../src/dataSource';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'FPGA-App-new';
  treeControl = new NestedTreeControl<FoodNode>(node => node.children);
  dataSource = new MatTreeNestedDataSource<FoodNode>();

  constructor() {
    this.dataSource.data = TREE_DATA;
  }

  hasChild = (_: number, node: FoodNode) => !!node.children && node.children.length > 0;
}
```

app.module.ts file contains relevant imported modules

**app.module.ts file**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatTreeModule, MatIconModule, MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material'
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatTreeModule, MatIconModule, MatButtonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I'm facing the same issue, I'd appreciate any input.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where my tree was being rendered like yours. At first I thought it was an issue with the `MatTreeModule` but discovered that I need to include the proper CSS in my component's style file.

The fix was to ensure the following styles are applied:

```
.example-tree-invisible {
  display: none;
}

.example-tree ul,
.example-tree li {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Source: https://stackblitz.com/angular/earqaagjdamd

Answer (score 1):

You have to install material-icons if not yet installed:

```
 npm install material-icons@latest
```

then you have to import material-icons into your styles.css:

```
@import "~material-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css";
```

then import MatIconModule in your app.module.ts:

```
 import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
 imports: [    MatIconModule,...]
```